# *ngIf doesn't evaluate after change in test condition in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am working on a multipage angular application. User selection on a page decides the view on the next page.

Here is the component code:

```
    export class DataComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

        constructor(private _router: Router, private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private _applicationService: ApplicationService) {        
          this.subscription = this._activatedRoute.params
          .subscribe((param: any) => {
            this.applicationId = param['applicationId'];                                                                                                                                                                  
          });                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        }

        ngOnInit(){
          this._applicationService.getApplication(this.applicationId)
          .subscribe(application =>  {this.application = application;});                   
        }
}
```

In the HTML template, I am evaluating a condition using *ngIf

`<div *ngIf="application?.flag">   Flag is true  </div>`

flag is a boolean which is fetched from the database.

Even though the value of boolean is true, div is not shown on the page. This happens only in internet explorer. I am suspecting the change detection of angular 2 is not working to refresh the view after loading the DOM.

Strangely if I open the console on the internet explorer, the page loads fine with the correct divs.

Please suggest how can I solve this problem.

I tried implementing the behavior using Resolve but I am still facing the same issue. App works perfectly in Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Edge browsers but fails in internet explorer without opening the console.

Here are the entries in the polyfills.ts:

```
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
```

I am using webpack.

Here is the resolve code:

```
@Injectable()
export class ApplicationResolve implements Resolve<Application>{

    constructor(private _applicationService: ApplicationService){}

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot){     
        return this._applicationService.getApplication(route.params['applicationId']);
    }

}
```

Here is the entry in the routing module:

```
{ path: 'clearData/:applicationId', component: DataComponent, resolve: {application: ApplicationResolve} }
```

Comment: refer this to format your codes
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: did you add Internet Explorer Polyfills ?

Comment: Please provide more code.

Comment: @mickdev I have added the IE polyfills

Comment: Change `<div *ngIf="this.application?.flag">   Flag is true  </div>` to `<div *ngIf="application?.flag">Flag is true</div>` and see if that resolve your issue

Comment: @mickdev removing this does not have any change in the behavior. I have edited the question to list the polyfills in the application.

Answer (score 0):

Try this workaround. First, set a boolean to false. Then set its value in ngOnInit hooks:

```
show:boolean = false

ngOnInit(){
          this._applicationService.getApplication(this.applicationId)
          .subscribe(application =>  {
              this.application = application;
              this.show = application.flag
          });                   
}
```

Then update your template like this :

```
<div *ngIf="show">Flag is true</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Creating a local variable has no effect on the behavior. Div loads on internet explorer only if console is open. Instead of fetching flag value in ngOnInit() I tried using resolve but still the same issue.